# How can I get Ubuntu to recognize the size of the disk it's on?

Tags: virtualbox, resize, disk-usage

I was coming dangerously close to filling up a virtualbox disk(.vdi) with Ubuntu on it.

So I enlarged the disk

```
    VBoxManage modifyhd YOUR_HARD_DISK.vdi --resize SIZE_IN_MB
```

I went from a 6GB disk to a 12GB disk.

Virtualbox recognizes the new disk size. However booting into the Ubuntu guest does not.

How can I tell Ubuntu to take a look at the disk size?

Ubuntu 11.04 64bit - Host

Ubuntu 10.04 32bit - Guest

Comment: What size does the disk utility (launch it from the bar) report?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The disk might be bigger but the partition *on that disk* is still the same.

You want to boot the virtual machine into a LiveCD environment and resize the partition:

- Download the iso
- Mount the ISO as the CD drive in the VM settings and boot the VM
- Press Del or F2 (whatever you need to change the boot order) and make it boot to CD first
- Get to the LiveCD environment.
- Use gparted (aka Partition editor) to resize your partition (select the partition, right click, resize, drag the slider up so it fills the disk)

Comment: Exactly right. I realized this immediately after posting here. I thought I had answered it too, I guess it didn't post?

Comment: What is `LiveCD` environment? Is it when you select `Try Ubuntu` instead of `Install Ubuntu`?

Comment: Gparted won't let me slide things. It sees the extra space as potentially another partition.
https://i.imgur.com/2X8x8O2.png